# Start and end touch events on different Element

Tags: javascript, touch, mouse

**Rant**

There is something I struggle to achieve on ios touch devices, which seems to work fine while working by mouse.

**Set**

A set in this example is defined by the three common steps (mousedown, mousemove and mouseup) and/or (touchstart, touchmove and touchend).

**Goal**

What is tried to get achieved is to start a set by either mousedown or touchstart, create an element in between and register the events of the same set on the newly created element.

- I click on the blue-element, hold the mouse, move it around on the
  green-element and register all events *(works)*
- I touch on the blue-element, hold the finger, move it around on the
  green-element and register all events *(does not work)*

**Example**

The sample below shows that one can start a set of mouseevents and finish it on a different element.

Unfortunately this does not seem to apply for touchevents. I can start a set yet not finish it on a different element in one set. One needs to end it first and start a new one to get its later events.

```
;var Test = {
    _End: function(){
        var tO = document.querySelector('#whateverOverlay');
        tO && tO.parentNode.removeChild(tO)
    },

    //e:={event}
    _Start: function(e){
        if(e){
            var tP = (e.target || e.srcElement);
            var tE = document.querySelector('#whateverOverlay');
            if(!tE){
                tE = document.createElement('div');
                tE.id = 'whateverOverlay';
                tE.style.cssText = 'position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; background: green';

                tE.onmousemove = function(){
                    console.log('Moving')
                };

                tE.onmouseup = function(){
                    console.log('Ending');
                    Test._End()
                };

                tE.ontouchmove = function(e){
                    e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
                    alert('Moving') //No console on my IPad
                };

                tE.ontouchend = function(e){
                    e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
                    alert('Ending'); //No console on my IPad
                    Test._End()
                };

                tP.appendChild(tE)
            }
        }
    },

    Init: function(){
        this._End();

        var tE = document.querySelector('#whateverLayer');
        if(!tE){
            tE = document.createElement('div');
            tE.id = 'whateverLayer';
            tE.style.cssText = 'position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; background: blue; z-index: 999';

            tE.onmousedown = function(e){
                Test._Start(e)
            };

            tE.ontouchstart = function(e){
                e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
                Test._Start(e)
            };

            document.body.appendChild(tE)
        }
    }
};

Test.Init();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2v3nw0sv/